# TextBox loses focus in listview when first character is typed

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am stuck with a strange problem for quite a while now. I am using listview to populate my screen. When I type anything in any text box it loses focus when the first element is typed. If I click on the textbox again then everything goes fine and I can type continuously. From the logs I can see that when the first element is typed in any EditText getView() gets called. Once I select the text field again then beforeTextChanged-onTextChanged-afterTextChanged are called continuously which is correct. Can someone help out please. I have tried solutions like making list view height to "fill_parent" and adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to my manifest.xml. Nothing works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `TextView` in list view item ? Where do you type text, maybe in `EditText` not in `TextView` ?

Comment: You are right, its EditText. I have edited the question. I am typing in the editText box. When the first character is typed EditText loses focus and getView gets called. Once I select it again the focus remains intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. getView() gets invoked internally whenever the screen dimensions are to be ascertained. In my case I had a hidden textview above the editText box. Whenever I was typing something in the editText box I was changing the visibility of the textView from GONE to VISIBLE. That is why the screen placement was changing and so getView() was getting invoked, resulting in the focus being lost. I changed the hidden textView from GONE to INVISIBLE. This way it kept its place in the display and hence even when it became VISIBLE, getView() didnt get invoked.